# Converting Decimals to mA

Tags: plc, actuator

I want to operate a actuator i.e. proportional valve with pwm module.
The input signal to my pwm module are standard signals 0..20mA, 4...20mA, 0..5V and 0..10V.

So to operate the valve I need to give value from my system. The D/A module then converts this into analog values.

How are these values converted from decimal to analog values?

I have attached the technical data of my actuator and my D/A module.

[AC2218](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kEH6.png)
[PWM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8QKT.png)

Comment: what kind of Hardware are you using? Which PLC? If possible, describe your analog input module where you want to connect the sensor, if it is a remote IO, detached from the PLC CPU.

Comment: I am using a IFM AC1421 PLC. My actuators are connected to the D/A module AC 2218 ifm.